# ActiveJob custom serializer - uninitialized constant NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I am trying to add a custom serializer to **ActiveJob** following [the ActiveJob Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#serializers). I have the following class, originally in the file **`app/lib/money_serializer.rb`,**

```rb
  class MoneySerializer < ActiveJob::Serializers::ObjectSerializer
  # ... 
  end
```

And in **`config/application.rb`**

```rb
  # ...
  config.active_job.custom_serializers << MoneySerializer
  # ...
```

I keep getting `uninitialized constant MoneySerializer (NameError)` which suggests to me that the Serializer is not being loaded on boot and tried placing it in different locations (including under config/initializers) without any luck.

What am I missing here? Where should I place an ActiveJob serializer?

Comment: Have you added the lib folder to your auto load paths? I think with newer version of Rails using zeigeist, you need to explicitly add that directory to the autoload paths

Comment: I was under the impression that, unlike`{Rails.root}/lib`, everything under `{Rails.root}/app` gets loaded automatically.  I have a couple of utility classes/modules there, and don't have any issue with them.

Comment: Ah mybad misread the path at the top :( Not enough coffee yet :P

Answer (score 4):

Based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37690), the issue is best solved as follows:

```rb
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join("app/serializers"))

Dir[Rails.root.join("app/serializers/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

Rails.application.config.active_job.custom_serializers << MoneySerializer
```

**Update**: In Rails 7, you can simply add the following to `config/application.rb`:

```rb
config.autoload_once_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join("app/serializers")]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you no longer get  the fancy hot reloading of serializers, and changes will require an app restart. But, at least the classes are available at boot/initialize time to let us add custom serializers.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone,

It seems to work when I put both the Serializer and the config in an initializer

```rb
  class MoneySerializer < ActiveJob::Serializers::ObjectSerializer
  # ... 
  end

  config.active_job.custom_serializers << MoneySerializer
```

Feels very odd to have a class here. Any other suggestions?